# Save data in a cakephp hasmany and belongsto association at once

Tags: php, cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-2.5

I know this question is asked here a many times but I also tried to follow the solutions provided at my best. As I am learning a cakephp some solutions seemed difficult to implement in a code. I am using cakephp 2.5.

What I am trying to do is creating a problem report with attached one or more uploads. Here is some of what I have implemented so far:-

**I have following models:**

- Candidate
- CandidatesProblemReport
- CandidatesProblemReportsUpload

**There associations are as follows:**

- CandidatesProblemReport hasMany CandidatesProblemReportsUpload
- Candidate hasMany CandidatesProblemReport
- CandidatesProblemReport belongsTo Candidate
- CandidatesProblemReportsUpload belongsTo CandidatesProblemReport

**Candidate.php**

```
    <?php

    class Candidate extends AppModel {

        public $name = 'Candidate';
        public $hasMany = array(

            'CandidatesProblemReport' => array(
                'className' => 'CandidatesProblemReport',
                'foreignKey' => 'candidate_id'
            )

        );
    }
```

**CandidatesProblemReport.php**

```
    <?php

    class CandidatesProblemReport extends AppModel {

        public $name = "CandidatesProblemReport";
        public $belongsTo = array(
            'Candidate' => array(
                'className' => 'Candidate'
            )
        );
        public $hasMany = array(
            'Uploads' => array(
                'className' => 'CandidatesProblemReportsUpload'
            ),
            'Replies' => array(
                'className' => 'CandidatesProblemReportsReply'
            )
        );    
    }
```

**CandidatesProblemReportsController.php**

```
    class CandidatesProblemReportsController extends AppController {

        public $name = "CandidatesProblemReports";

        // ############# Report a Problem #############
        // ********************************************
        public function create() {
            $userid = $this->Auth->user('id'); // Grabs the current user id
            $this->set('userId', $userid); // Sends the current user id to the form

            if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->data)):

                $this->CandidatesProblemReport->create();

                $report = $this->CandidatesProblemReport->save($this->request->data);
                if (!empty($report)):         
                    $this->request->data['CandidatesProblemReportsUpload']['candidates_problem_report_id'] = $this->CandidatesProblemReport->id;
                endif;

                if ($this->CandidatesProblemReport->saveAssociated($this->request->data)):

                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your report has been submitted '
                            . 'successfully. Thank you!');

                    $this->redirect(array(
                        'action' => 'viewall')
                    );
                else:
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your report could not be submitted, '
                            . 'please try again');
                endif;

            endif;
        }
    }
```

**create.ctp**

```
<h1>Create a report</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('CandidatesProblemReport', array('type' => 'file'));

echo $this->Form->input('CandidatesProblemReport.report_subject');

echo $this->Form->input('CandidatesProblemReport.report_handle_department', array(
    'options' => array(
        'Technical' => 'Technical',
        'Sales' => 'Sales',
        'Support' => 'Support',
        'Other' => 'Other'
    )
));
echo $this->Form->input('CandidatesProblemReport.report_description');

echo $this->Form->input('CandidatesProblemReport.report_date', array(
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
);

echo $this->Form->input('CandidatesProblemReport.candidate_id', array(
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'value' => $userId)
);
?>

<div>
    <p><strong>Upload Screenshot/Files</strong></p>
    <hr>
</div>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('CandidatesProblemReportsUpload.0.report_upload', array(
    'type' => 'file'
));
?>
<button class="add-new-upload" type="button">Add more</button>
<?php
echo $this->Form->end('submit');

echo $this->Html->script('jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    $('.add-new-upload').click(function () {
        $('.file').append('<input type="file" name="data[CandidatesProblemReportsUpload]['
                + i +
                '][report_upload]" id="CandidatesProblemReportsUpload'
                + i +
                'ReportUpload">');
        i++;
    });
</script>
```

Now what is happening is I am able to save the main model data i.e. CandidatesProblemReports but when I saveAssociated data it again saves the main model creating second duplicate entry but the uploads are not getting saved.

Comment: Besides the obvious problems with your code, are you aware that CakePHP doesn't store file upload data automatically? ie, what do you expect to happen when `CandidatesProblemReportsUpload` records are being saved?

Comment: As @ndm said, handling the file uploads and its database records won't happen out of the box. You need to process those uploads and change the data array your pass to the Model in a way that can be saved `array('FieldName'=>'Field Value (File Name for example)')`

Comment: Thanks @ndm for your reply, yes I know CakePHP doesn't handle file upload automatically. I just want the data to be saved in their respective tables, as of now only the main model's i.e. CandidatesProblemReport 's data is being saved two times (two diff. records).

Comment: @AymanB. how do I change the data array before passing it to the Model. As of now I am modifying the data array by passing the `ID` of the `CandidateProblemReport` saved before before it is being saved as associated data.

Comment: @ndm forget about file type field also its not saving text type data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Saving data with associations

That's the expected behavior, `saveAssociated()` is not ment to save only the associated records, it will save the main record as well, so you should use `saveAssociated()` only, no need to manually set the foreign key, etc, CakePHP will do that automatically.

**Controller**

```
public function create() {
    // ...

    if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->data)):

        $this->CandidatesProblemReport->create();

        if ($this->CandidatesProblemReport->saveAssociated($this->request->data)):
            // ...
        endif;

    endif;
}
```

### Mind your aliases

The reason for your upload records not being created, is that you are not using the proper alias in your form/data, you've set the alias to be `Uploads`, but in your form you are using `CandidatesProblemReportsUpload`, and so CakePHP will ignore this data.

**Form**

```
echo $this->Form->input('Uploads.0.report_upload', array(
    'type' => 'file'
));
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    $('.add-new-upload').click(function () {
        $('.file').append('<input type="file" name="data[Uploads]['
                + i +
                '][report_upload]" id="Uploads'
                + i +
                'ReportUpload">');
        i++;
    });
</script>
```

### Storing file data

As mentioned in the comments, CakePHP doesn't handle file upload data out of the box, you'll have to prepare it in beforehand so that it is for example being stored on disk, and the model stores the path to the file.

While the above code should generally work, it will most likely trigger an error as it will try to store the file upload array in the database instead of flat data.

There are plugins out there that can handle file uploads, check them out, also search here on stackoverflow and check the docs for examples on how to modify data before it is being saved.

For starters:

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforevalidate**
- **https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload**

Comment: OMG O.o I totally forgot the aliases, I am sure now it must work, Thanks! @ndm, I ll get back to you soon as I am done with implementation. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks man, As I thought it worked in a first try, Thank you so much!!

Comment: would you help me with how do I reply to the current report which already submitted/exists from `CandidatesProblemReports` Controller? Currently I am trying to pass the `candidates_problem_report_id` from the `CandidatesProblemReports` Form.

Comment: @Iglance3 That would be something for a new question where you can add code and an explanation of the problem that you are facing.

Comment: ok I figured it out... I just saved the data array with `$this->MainModel->AssociatedModel->save(data);`

Answer (score 0):

You can user `$this->CandidatesProblemReport->saveAssociated($this->request->data)` code to save associate data in multiple tables using one query.