# CakePHP: Unable to save data to parent entity via belongsTo associated child

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

### Problem description

I'm trying to configure a CakePHP 3.7 API to save associated data in a child-first manner. The entities - for the sake of example, lets call them `Users` and `Persons` - and their relationships are as follows:

**UsersTable.php**

```
...
  $this->belongsTo('Persons', [
    'foreignKey' => 'person_id',
    'joinType' => 'LEFT',
    'className' => 'MyPlugin.Persons',
  ]);
...
```

**PersonsTable.php**

```
  $this->hasOne('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'person_id',
    'className' => 'MyPlugin.Users'
  ]);
```

In their respective entities, they each have one another's property visibility set to `true`. What I'm trying to do is `POST` to the `/users/` route (`UsersController.php`) and have it also save the `Persons` object included. The payload is as such:

```
{
    "username": "foo",
    "password": "bar",
    "persons": {
        "dob": "1982-07-03",
    }
}
```

The relevant part of the saving method is below, from `UsersController.php`:

```
  if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->getData())) {
    $data = $this->request->getData();
    $newEntity = $this->Users->newEntity($data, ['associated' => 'Persons']);

    $savedEntity =  $this->Users->save($newEntity);
  ...
```

### The error

This produces the following SQL error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column 'person_id' violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL: Failing row contains (1, null, foo, bar)

I understand this is because Cake is attempting to save to `Users` without having a `person_id` to satisfy the foreign key constraint. It's not possible to reverse this FK relationship in my application domain as we desire leftward one-to-many relationship (User -> 1 Person).

I suspect sending an `id` in the `persons` object of the `JSON` payload will allow this to save correctly. However, for various reasons, this isn't possible at runtime. For example, this is how it's shown in the ["Saving Data" CakePHP Book page](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongsto-associations)...

```
$data = [
  'title' => 'First Post',
  'user' => [
      'id' => 1,
      'username' => 'mark'
  ]
];

...
$article = $articles->newEntity($data, [
    'associated' => ['Users']
]);

$articles->save($article);
```

I know the following would also likely work as [suggested by xPfqHZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32143779/5012644) for a similar issue, as `Persons` can save to `Users`, but it feels less suitable as compared to what I'm trying to do and feels as if there is a way via the associations on `Users`.

```
  if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->getData())) {
    $data = $this->request->getData();
    $newEntity = $this->Users->Persons->newEntity($data, ['associated' => 'Persons']);

    $savedEntity =  $this->Users->Persons->save($newEntity);
  ...
```

### Workings

Now I believe this used to be possible in CakePHP 2.X, as stated in [this answer by ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26656379/5012644) on a similar question where a person is attempting to save the `belongsTo` associated entity and it's parent `hasOne` entity in one request via the `belongsTo` entity.

> That's the expected behavior, saveAssociated() is not meant to save only the associated records, it will save the main record as well, so you should use saveAssociated() only, no need to manually set the foreign key, etc, CakePHP will do that automatically.
>
> **Controller**
>
> ```
> public function create() {
>     if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->data)):
>         $this->CandidatesProblemReport->create();
>         if ($this->CandidatesProblemReport->saveAssociated($this->request->data)):
>             // ...
>         endif;
>     endif;
> }
> ```

However, I'm not able to find or use the `saveAssociated()` method upon the `Cake\ORM\Table` object which the `Users` entity inherits from, in the documentation. Calling it produces a method not found error. This method only appears to exist on the `Cake\ORM\Association` object as detailed in the [documentation](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.ORM.Association.html#_saveAssociated). Unless I'm missing the obvious, is there a way to use this or is it used internally by `BelongsTo()` and its sibling methods?

#### Logging / Dumping entity

Using `Cake\Log\Log::error($newEntity);` or `die(var_dump($newEntity));` shows the `Users` data of the payload hydrated into an object, but I don't see the `Persons` object attached (see below).

```
object(MyPlugin\Model\Entity\User)[299]
  public 'username' => string 'foo' (length=3)
  public 'password' => string 'bar' (length=3)
  public '[new]' => boolean true
  public '[accessible]' => 
    array (size=5)
      '*' => boolean false
      'person_id' => boolean true
      'username' => boolean true
      'password' => boolean true
      'person' => boolean true
  public '[dirty]' => 
    array (size=2)
      'username' => boolean true
      'password' => boolean true
  public '[original]' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '[virtual]' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '[hasErrors]' => boolean false
  public '[errors]' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '[invalid]' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '[repository]' => string 'MyPlugin.Users' (length=17)
```

Attempting to `\Cake\Log\Log::error($savedEntity);` shows nothing in the log file.

#### `save()` associations arguments

Another solution I considered was using the `$options['associated]` of `save()` as shown in the [documentation](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_save) (extract below). With this set to true as below, the error still occurred.

> save( Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity , array $options [] )
>
> ... **associated**: If true it will save 1st level associated entities as they are found in the passed $entity whenever the property defined for the association is marked as dirty. If an array, it will be interpreted as the list of associations to be saved. It is possible to provide different options for saving on associated table objects using this key by making the custom options the array value. If false no associated records will be saved. (default: true) ...

`UsersController.php`:

```
  if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->getData())) {
    $data = $this->request->getData();
    $newEntity = $this->Users->newEntity($data, ['associated' => 'Persons']);

    $savedEntity =  $this->Users->save($newEntity, ['associated' => true]);
  ...
```

### Summary

Without going through the `PersonsController.php` and utilising its `hasOne` relationship, I'm not having much luck getting my `Users` and `Persons` data to save through the `UsersController.php`.

If I've missed any important information, or you have questions/need more, please ask! I might have missed something obvious, but I'd appreciate any suggestions/solutions possible.

Comment: The property name for `belongsTo` and `hasOne` associations is by default the _singular_ underscored variant of the association name, so your data should use `person` instead of `persons`.

Comment: @ndm _sigh_. RTFM... better. Good spot - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ndm identified, the error lay in the posted data. As per the ["Saving Data: Saving BelongsTo Associations"](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongsto-associations) page of the documentation:

> When saving belongsTo associations, the ORM expects a single nested entity named with the **singular**, **underscored** version of the association name.

The posted key `persons` should have been `person`. Equally, if the entity were named `PersonSnapshots`, the relevant key in the payload hydrated into the entities would need to have been `person_snapshot`.